# How to set broker.SubscriberOptions in go-micro

Tags: go, rabbitmq, microservices, go-micro

I am trying to configure a RabbitMQ broker using the `go-micro` framework. I have noticed that the broker interface in go-micro has a `broker.SubscriberOptions` [struct](https://github.com/micro/go-micro/blob/master/broker/options.go) which allows configuring the parameters I am looking for (AutoAck, Queue name and so on) however I am unable to figure out how to pass this when starting a broker.

This is how a simple rabbit go-micro setup would look like

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/micro/go-micro/server"
    "github.com/micro/go-plugins/broker/rabbitmq"

    micro "github.com/micro/go-micro"
)


func main() {
    // Create a new service. Optionally include some options here.
    service := micro.NewService(
        micro.Name("go-micro-rabbit"),
        micro.Broker(rabbitmq.NewBroker()),
    )

    // Init will parse the command line flags.
    service.Init()

    // Register handler
    proto.RegisterGreeterHandler(service.Server(), new(Greeter))

    micro.RegisterSubscriber("micro-exchange", service.Server(), myFunc, server.SubscriberQueue("my-queue"))

    // Run the server
    if err := service.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The `micro.RegisterSubscriber` method takes in a list of `server.SubscriberOption` but does not allow me to set the `broker.SubscriberOptions` and the `rabbitmq.NewBroker` allows setting `broker.Options` but once again, not `broker.SubscriberOptions`

I have dug in the code of go-micro but have been unable to figure out how the `broker.Subscribe` method (Which exposes the correct struct) is called or by who.

Is this possible at all? Is it maybe something not yet fully fleshed out in the API?